# Could not able to listen audio notification via WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, voip, freeswitch

I have setup WebRTC using verto module of freeswitch and we have done everything successfully just the one thing we are experiencing since long time and could not get any solution.

I want to play a account balance when ever any user try to make call and if there is a no balance in account need to play "Not enough credit in account".
Now the problem is Freeswitch actually playing those notification which we can able to listen properly if we make call using soft-phone but i could not able to listen it via WebRTC web phone.

any one can help me to fix this issue?

Comment: is this after Answer or Pre-answer?

Comment: To just conform verto setup is good on server side, Check with `https://tryit.jssip.net/js/`. Login with one of your sip account, Dial and check if its working.